# Como puedo llamar un método no estático en la misma clase java

Tags: java-8

lo que sucede es que tengo un caso en el cual me establecen determinadas condiciones para los métodos, las cuales son:

- para el método picar dependiendo del material del pico se calcula y retorna la duración de la animación de picar y se agrega el bloque
- El método agregarBloque se debe llamar en el método picar
- No hay métodos estáticos

el problema es que no se como llamar el método agregarBloque en picar ya que me sale este error:
(las otras clases y parte del código lo omití para ser mas preciso)

> ```
> ./Personaje.java:69: error: unreachable statement
>         agregarBloque (b);
>         ^
> ./Personaje.java:70: error: missing return statement
>     }
>     ^
> ```
>
> 2 errors

#### TESTEADOR AUTOMÁTICO

```
public class Personaje {

    //los atributos

    private String nombre;
    private ArrayList<Espacio> inventario;
    private Espacio espacio;

    //método constructor

    Personaje (String nombreDelPersonaje)
    {
        this.nombre = nombreDelPersonaje;
        ArrayList<Espacio> inventario = new ArrayList<Espacio>();
        this.espacio = new Espacio();
    }

    //los métodos
    
    public double picar (String materialPico, Bloque b)
    {
        double picar = 0;
        if (materialPico == "madera")
        {
            picar = b.getResistencia() * 0.75;
        }
        else if (materialPico == "piedra")
        {
            picar = b.getResistencia() * 0.375;
        }
        else if (materialPico == "hierro")
        {
            picar = b.getResistencia() * 0.25;
        }
        else if (materialPico == "diamante")
        {
            picar = b.getResistencia() * 0.2;
        }
        else if (materialPico == "oro")
        {
            picar = b.getResistencia() * 0.125;
        }
        return picar;
        agregarBloque (b);
    }
    
    public void agregarBloque (Bloque b)
    {
        if (espacio.getPila().size() > 0 || espacio.getPila().size()< 3 && b == espacio.getPila().get(0))
        {
            espacio.getPila().add (b);    
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Tienes que hacer la llamada al método antes del `return`,  no después de él. Después de `return` no debes poner nunca nada.

Comment: muchas gracias es correcto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los métodos dentro de la propia clase se llaman como lo estás haciendo.

Los problemas que veo en tu código son dos:

1. Para comparar cadenas debes usar `equals()`, no `==`
2. En un método, lo último que debes poner es el `return`, porque a partir de ahí el código retorna al llamador, sin ejecutar todo lo que esté después de esa línea.

Así debería funcionar, salvo otros errores:

```
public double picar (String materialPico, Bloque b)
{
    double picar = 0;
    if ( materialPico.equals("madera") )
    {
        picar = b.getResistencia() * 0.75;
    }
    else if ( materialPico.equals("piedra") )
    {
        picar = b.getResistencia() * 0.375;
    }
    else if ( materialPico.equals("hierro") )
    {
        picar = b.getResistencia() * 0.25;
    }
    else if ( materialPico.equals("diamante") )
    {
        picar = b.getResistencia() * 0.2;
    }
    else if ( materialPico.equals("oro") )
    {
        picar = b.getResistencia() * 0.125;
    }
    agregarBloque (b);
    return picar;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, había intentado de todo y no había caído en cuenta de eso

Comment: A caso el último bloque (el del oro) no debería ser `else if`?

Comment: @Mateo, sí, tienes razón, porque aquí se compara por un valor en específico, ahora corrijo la respuesta. Gracias por señalarlo.

Comment: Me parecía raro. Además así como estaba no debería compilar siquiera. Por nada.